# How to free memory in the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I have the following lines of code in a kernel module. The KFREE line causes The OS to hang. Without it KEDR reports a memory leak. So how do I free p?

```
char * p = KMALLOC(100, GFP_ATOMIC);
p = dentry_path_raw(dentry, p, 100) ;
printk(KERN_EMERG " %s" , p);
KFREE(p);
```

KFREE is defined as follows:

```
# define KFREE(a)   kfree((a))
```

KMALLOC is defined as follows:

```
# define KMALLOC(a,b)   kmalloc((a),(b))
```

Comment: You need a second variable to store the return value from calling `dentry_path_raw(dentry, p, 100)`. Right now you're freeing whatever that returns - not what you allocated.

Comment: Thank you. I actually just changed this: p = dentry_path_raw(dentry, p, 100) ;    to this dentry_path_raw(dentry, p, 100) ; and that made it work. I do not need the return value.. it was a noob mistake. Thank you again

Comment: And how exactly will you know the beginning of the returned string? You **have to** use returned value.